# count of columns having a particular flag in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 10 columns to store flags which can only be Y or N against a name like below

```
NAME    FLAG1   FLAG2   FLAG3   FLAG4   FLAG5   …   FLAG10
----------------------------------------------------------
name1     Y       N       Y       Y       Y          N
name2     N       N       Y       N       N          Y
name3     Y       Y       Y       N       Y          N
```

I want to get the count of Y and N for every name.

```
NAME   Y     N
---------------
name1  4     6
name2  2     8
name3  5     5
```

Looking for an oracle/sql query with good performance, the table holds millions of records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [REGEXP_COUNT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF20014) to count character occurence :

```
SELECT name,
   REGEXP_COUNT(Flag1||Flag2||Flag3||Flag5||Flag6||Flag7||Flag8||Flag9||Flag10,'Y')  AS Y,
   REGEXP_COUNT(Flag1||Flag2||Flag3||Flag5||Flag6||Flag7||Flag8||Flag9||Flag10,'N')  AS N
FROM t
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `DECODE`:

```
SELECT name,
   DECODE(Flag1, 'Y', 1, 'N', 0) + 
   DECODE(Flag2, 'Y', 1, 'N', 0) +  
   --...
   DECODE(Flag10, 'Y', 1, 'N', 0) AS Y,
   DECODE(Flag1, 'Y', 0, 'N', 1) + 
   DECODE(Flag2, 'Y', 0, 'N', 1) +  
   --...
   DECODE(Flag10, 'Y', 0, 'N', 1) AS N
FROM table;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b0ac734d3ab023dfd5455bb5bfd30f8a)**

---

Using `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT name, SUM(DECODE(FlagV,'Y', 1, 'N', 0)) AS Y,
       SUM(DECODE(FlagV, 'Y', 0, 'N', 1)) AS N
FROM t
UNPIVOT ( FlagV FOR Flag IN (Flag1,Flag2,Flag10)) unpvt
GROUP BY name;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo 2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4d29016d77cb870b8519762e68a9b1e7)**

---

Note: If you want to hold only 2 values 'Y'/'N' (true/false) I would suggest to use `0` and `1` values as `NUMERIC(1)`. Then you simply add columns without any decoding.

Comment: Wow, brilliant!